# Java Object Creation Inside Infinite Loop

Tags: java

I am attempting to write daemon process. Below is my sample code snippet.

```
public void listener() {
    MyObject obj = null;

    while(true) {
        obj = new MyObject();
        obj.process();
    }
}
```

Or shall i create like this

```
public void listener() {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    while(true) {
        obj.process();
    }
}
```

`process()` method will do database `select` and `insert into` table, connect web service and get the response message and send the message to user.

Which one is the correct way?

Comment: That depends on what `MyObject` and `MyObject.process` are and what this thing is even supposed to do.

Comment: process will do.. db select and insert, connect web service and process the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question for freshers. I appreciate.

The first one, This will create a new Object o for each iteration of the loop. Garbage collector will clean often.

The second one, thus it will be available for all the time. If you want to reuse the object all the time then go for it.

Since it is infinite process, then just go for second option to reuse the objects.

Answer (score 1):

That entirely depends on what `MyObject` does and how `process(()` is implemented. As a general notion, if `MyObject` is stateless, and one `process` call won't leave any leftovers that could disturb the subsequent call, you could probably optimize and use a single instance instead of thrashing the garbage collector with a new instance in every iteration.

Comment: @ Mureinik. Thanks for your answer. Can you please say, what you mean stateless.

Comment: @EasyToDownVoteHardToAns stateless means just that - it has no state (i.e., data members), and calling any method can't the result of any subsequent method calls

Comment: @ Mureinik Thanks and noted.

Answer (score 0):

In first sample, you create `obj` until your heap size is full and when heap size is full JVM throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

In second sample you have one object and you always call process() method.

Comment: Since after every loop iteration the newly created objects are not accessible anymore, they will be garbage collected before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.